# Oracle Forms 10.1.2 run in EDGE/CHROME

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Like we all know Internet Explorer will retire in 2022. I have an app in Oracle Forms 10.1.2. In future I'm planning to rewrite the app for other technology. However, it must be available during this process.

Is there a possibility to run Oracle Forms in this version on MS EDGE or CHROME?

Answer (score 0):

We've got number of old Oracle Forms applications. Yes, they run with MS Internet Explorer & JInitiator.

Google Chrome offers extension that - as they say - enables you to run Forms in Chrome. Have a look at [ThinForms Enterprise](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/thinforms-enterprise-for/nmjefghbgfcpoobigfbalocpncklkjhk?hl=en):

> The ThinForms Enterprise Chrome Extension allows you to run Oracle Forms and Oracle EBS Applets & Applications, as well as Oracle Discoverer directly from Google Chrome on Windows, OSX and Linux, or from Microsoft Edge (Chromium).

Comment: how much it costs? I'm worried that it's a 3-rd party software, and my company won't allow that

Comment: I don't know the price, you should contact the author. (Not related to the ThinForms Enterprise), read https://pitss.com/us/2021/05/20/the-end-of-internet-explorer-how-does-it-impact-oracle-forms/ for some more info about the issue you might be having. It is not that your old Forms application will suddenly stop working - you'll still be able to use it on the last Internet Explorer version you have on your PCs; just don't upgrade to a newer operating system version which might NOT have the IE installed at all. That might be OK until you migrate to other technology.

Comment: So if we have IE 11 installed on the PC, after the end date, can we still use it?

Comment: I believe so, yes.